# Eigenvalues and eigenspaces of automorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-algebras, generalized-eigenvector

Consider $T,S: \mathfrak{g} \longrightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ automorphisms of the $n$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.  Is there any relation between the eigenvalues of $T$ and $S$ and the eigenvalues of the automorphism $T \circ S: \mathfrak{g} \longrightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ (or vice-versa)?

The specific problem I'm dealing with is considering $T = e^{\hbox{ad}(X)}$ and $S = e^{\hbox{ad}(Y)}$.

I believe that the relation may not exist, but I'm not sure.

Any hint, reference or counterexample is appreciated.

Comment: In general, no. If $T$ and $S$ commute, however, the eigenvalues will be given by products of the eigenvalues of $T$ and of $S$ (see the non-accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337981/eigenvalues-of-the-product-of-two-diagonalizable-commuting-matrices), for example)

Comment: I was trying to avoid the commutation, because in the problem I'm currently working on it is too much to ask. I don't think that there is a easy answer for that and probably I will have to add some additional hypothesis.  Anyway, thank you.

Comment: What can we say about the eigenspaces?

Comment: Same thing really. If they commute, the eigenspaces play nicely together but otherwise they could do anything